# Что такое lParam pywin32

Tags: python, minecraft, pywin32, координаты

Пытаюсь сделать программу для **свернутого** окна, чтобы та делала клик **на определенных координатах**, используя pywin32

```
import win32gui, win32con, win32ui, win32api

hwnd = win32gui.FindWindowEx(0, 0, None, 'Minecraft 1.8')
pycwnd = win32ui.CreateWindowFromHandle(hwnd)



cords = win32gui.ScreenToClient(hwnd, (300, 300))
x = cords[0]
y = cords[1]
lParam = win32api.MAKELONG(x, y)
print(lParam) # return 15794438
print(x, y)

pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_LBUTTONDOWN, win32con.MK_LBUTTON, lParam);
pycwnd.SendMessage(win32con.WM_LBUTTONUP, 0, lParam);
```

Для реализации клика по координатам, как я понял, следует использоват lParam. Несмотря на многочисленные темы от пользователей, фигурирует в них лишь блокнот/браузер, но вот DirectXInput игры не затрагиваются. К тому же, обсуждения были созданы более 7-ми лет назад, поэтому на актуальность не стоит полагаться. Официальной документации я по pywin32 не нашел, кроме http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/contents.html , правда там особо не поясняется использование lParam.

В моем понимании lParam:

1. Параметр координат клика.
2. Координаты представляют из себя LONG значение, получаемое через функции **MAKELONG()**
3. Для точности координаты должны быть внутренними, тоесть указывать на координаты внутри окна, чего можно добиться через **ScreenToClient()**
4. Отправлять запрос следует в нужное окно, дабы lParam был принят и обработан, чего я добиваюсь через **CreateWindowFromHandle()**

Если я где-то ошибаюсь, то прошу у вас помощи переосмыслить lParam, и наконец понять, как он работает

Comment: wParam, lParam - это просто общее название для параметров, которые для разных типов сообщений окна могут значить совершенно разное. В вашем случае нужно смотреть именно параметры сообщения WM_LBUTTONDOWN. Судя по информации [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-lbuttondown) для данного типа сообщений в этом параметре передаются x, y координаты события относительно левого верхнего угла клиентской области.

Comment: "переосмыслить lParam, и наконец понять, как он работает" - он никак не работает, это просто параметр. Если что-то не работает, я бы посоветовал начать проверять работу с самого начала кода - вдруг у вас FindWindowEx вообще окно не находит, а вы на SendMessage грешите.

Comment: @insolor Если бы FindWindowEx не находил окно, он бы выдал мне соответственную ошибку, о том что handle неверный, но этого не просходит. Клик доставляется в окно, значит оно найдено правильно.  Не работают координаты, из этого я сделал вывод, что неполадка в них

Comment: FindWindowEx не выдает никаких ошибок, он просто 0 вернет, если окно не найдено. "Клик доставляется в окно" - как вы это определили? "Не работают координаты, из этого я сделал вывод, что неполадка в них" - координаты не могут работать, это просто числа.

Comment: Разве если нажатие происходит, клик не доставляется?

Comment: @insolor сказали бы лучше что-нибудь по делу, чем словами футболить. @syaveloo у меня в pywinauto, если вызывать PostMessage через `ctypes`, а не через `pywin32`, клик и координаты обычно работают. Это может зависеть от приложения (кое-где разная конвертация абсолютных и относительных координат нужна, но в целом работает). LParam я привожу к типу `from ctypes import wintypes; wintypes.LPARAM(lParam)`. Может быть, такой способ прокатит. Звать нужно функцию `ctypes.windll.user32.PostMessageW`.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, так и вы не отвечаете по делу. "Клик доставляется в окно" - как вы это определили? Клик происходит, но не в том месте, или что?

Comment: @insolor Да, клик происходит в нужном окне, но не по координатом

Comment: @VasilyRyabov Спасибо за совет, в ближайший час протестирую

Comment: @VasilyRyabov, Объясните пожалуйста, как отправить  сообщение в окно pywinauto?
hwnd = win32gui.FindWindow(None, 'mc')
app = pywinauto.Application().connect(path='javaw.exe')
lParam = wintypes.LPARAM(win32api.MAKELONG(150, 215))
ctypes.windll.user32.PostMessageW(app.mc, 0x0002, 0, lParam)
Возвращает pywinauto.findwindows.ElementNotFoundError, мол окно не найдено, хотя  имя окна - "mc", указано корректно.

Comment: Имя окна можно проверить в списке, который возвращает `[w.window_text() for w in app.windows()]`. А так нужно использовать `app.window(title="Some title").handle` либо `app.SomeTitle.handle`.